# How to get definition of index alias?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

After I update document it disappears from index alias. I guess there must be some filter on this alias. How can I get definition of index alias?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [index alias endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#alias-retrieving)

To get a list of **all** aliases :

- `/_all/_alias`

Or you can filter by indices and alias name (wildcards are accepted)

- `/{index}/_alias/{alias}`

Comment: I thought that maybe there's other way. This returns
`my_main_index": {
    "aliases": {
      "alias_im_interested_in": {}
   }
}`
 but if understand this alias adds nothing except new name?

Comment: Yes, this response indicates that the alias does not define any filter. The number of documents in the index and the alias should be the same. What do you mean by the document disappear ? It is not returned by a search query ?

Comment: Yes. I cannot find it anymore.